# Nestjs with Typeorm No migrations are pending

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i have a fresh database, i generate migration and then i try to run it but this is the result:

> query: SELECT VERSION() AS `version`
> query: SELECT VERSION() AS `version`
> Data Source has been initialized!
> query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'laps5' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
> query: SELECT * FROM `testdb`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
> No migrations are pending

It work correctly until i have updated my package.json and now it can't work.

This is my config:

```
export const datasourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
type: 'mysql',
host: 'localhost',
username: 'xxxx',
password: 'xxxxxx',
synchronize: false,
entities: [Token, UserAnag, User],
migrations: ['/migrations/*.js'],
database: process.env.DATABASE,
};
```

My migration folder is on root of project. I also must change entities option
from:

```
  entities: [__dirname + '/src/entities/*.js'],
```

to

```
 entities: [Token, UserAnag, User]
```

because the generate command return to me "No changes in database schema were found"

So actually i can create migration but if i try to run it doesn't work.
I search and try a lot of solution, like change my migration folder position into dist and build solution before launch migration but without it work

The command i use to run migration is:

> npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./db.datasource.ts

where typeorm is defined as

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development typeorm-ts-node-commonjs

In my Production system, it seem's work correctly. Locally none.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually fix it the same way you did with the entities, although it becomes harder to manage once your project grows.

For the entities I would suggest to create a barrel index file to export all your entities, so you can:

```
import * as entitiesMap from '@project-name/entities';

const entities = Object.values(entitiesMap);
```

I have entities defined in a `lib`, read more here [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries).

As for the migrations: TypeOrm can't locate them. Long story short: it tries to resolve them starting from the root and finds the folder with `.ts` migrations.
To get to the `.js` you will need to amend the path `__dirname + '/**/migrations/*.js'` or `__dirname + '*/**/migrations/*.js'`.

Try adding console log of the resulting path in your config.

Comment: OK for the Entities but i can't understand why the old method is not working now.
About Migrations i verify that point to correct folder and it works! The folder is correct with .js file inside (i make the migration with -o for js output) but doesn't work

Comment: This is my `data-source.ts` file: 

```export default new DataSource({
  ...
  entities: ['./libs/entities/**/*.entity.ts'],
  migrations: ['./apps/web-server/src/migrations/*.ts']
});```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a bug in TypeORM 0.3.12

Check this:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9860
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9766

> The solution, as mentioned there,
> is to downgrade to 0.3.11 and wait for the problem to be fixed.

```
npm i typeorm@0.3.11
```