# NestJs TypeORM No changes in database schema were found

Tags: node.js, migration, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

So I created a new project and implemented a user entity, but when I run the command to create the migration it doesn't work and the message is

> No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command

Two months ago I created another project with nest and the migrations work. It has the same configuration (literally for the current project I copied and pasted the db and migrations configuration). But my node version was 18.12 and typeorm was 0.3.11 and now I have node 18.15 and typeorm 0.3.12. I use windows 11.
Could it be something in the versioning?

My config is:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";

export const dataSourceOptions : DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    migrations:["dist/db/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
}

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

and the package.json

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm": "npm run build && npx typeorm -d dist/db/data-source.js",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
  },
```

and my files in dist are:
[image: files in dist]

Please help me I don't know what is wrong with the paths because this way it works

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";
import { Usuario } from "../src/usuario/entities/usuario.entity";
import { tablaUsuario1679500306406 } from "./migrations/1679500306406-tabla-usuario";

export const dataSourceOptions : DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    // entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    entities: [ Usuario ],
    // migrations:["dist/db/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
    migrations: [tablaUsuario1679500306406]
}

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75734745/21374758 this is the only way I made it work  but i don't know why writing the path does not work

Comment: I have run into the same error before and doing `npm run build` always picks up the new changes. I am suggesting this in case it's not an issue with the file directory/paths

Comment: I run npm run build and I still get the same message

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to generate migration.

When you are generating migration, it detects difference between your entities model and database. If your changes in entities auto generate new database then there is no difference and that is why you can see message:

> No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command

To solve this problem you have to clear your database, for example you can use script in pgadmin:

```sql
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

and then run generating migration.

Comment: No, my database didn't have tables and I wanted to create them through the migration, but it didn't recognize the new entities

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  could be a bug in TypeORM 0.3.12

I read about the problem here:
[Nestjs with Typeorm No migrations are pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75493208/nestjs-with-typeorm-no-migrations-are-pending)

The solution, as mentioned there,
is to downgrade to 0.3.11.

npm i typeorm@0.3.11

Comment: thanks, I tried downgrading but the problem remains